# How to create a view page displaying data only from a specific id? I'm using Yii Framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

In my main.php, I created a link and it's supposed to display all announcements that the current user posted but instead, I'm getting ALL the announcements from every user.

How do I change this?

This is my link code:

```
<a class="more" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('announcement')?>" >
    <?php switch_lang('View Announcements', '查看更多', FALSE)?>
</a>
```

And based on my code from the actionShow() from the controller, this is the code:

```
 public function actionShow($id)
{
    $post=$this->loadModel($id);
    $comment=$this->newComment($post);
        $attachments=Attachments::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(
                'content_id' => $id,
                ));
    $this->render('show',array(
        'model'=>$post,
        'comment'=>$comment,
            'attachments'=>$attachments
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to work the show action of whatever controller it is a part of, do this -

```
 <a class="more" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('<controllername>/show',array('id'=>$id))?>" >
```

You can re-route the action to any name like the 'announcement' part you gave in the question in the [urlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) of main.php subsequently.